# Set user attributes modificable only by admin

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I would like to define user attributes that the user can not modify by himself (i.e. readonly for the user using the dashboard) but that the admin should be able to modify using the management console. I have been able to add custom claims to the user profile and map them on the underlying JDBC user store attributes.

Now my goal is to associate with each user a set of allowed resources assigned by the administrator. I can not achieve the same goal assigning to the user a certain role because each resource has a certain id. Just to make an example I want to assign to the user the list of the company cars that he is allowed to  use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this by using the xacml policy.Your can refer below link for simple xacml policy sample[1].
[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/09/02/how-write-xacml-policies-1/